# Error in plugin: Invalid JSON provided, unable to parse

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins, influx-line-protocol

I'm using docker to bring up Telegraf,InfluxDB,Grafana.
I'm using amqp_consumer input plugin in Telegraf conf file.
I'm getting the error
*E! [inputs.amqp_consumer] Error in plugin: Invalid JSON provided, unable to parse*.
I have enabled debug level log in Telegraf conf also but I cannot see what is the json input Telegraf is receiving.

Can someone point out how to view the JSON messages received to Telegraf.

Comment: There is no option to do this right now unfortunately. What I would suggest using an amqp client and see what that client is showing.

Comment: @powersj : Yeah I am using RabbitMQ to view the messages. But there are lot of messages so to identify which message is causing the issue is hard.